# convert a string to hexcode

Tags: php, javascript

I want to convert a string to a colorhexcode in JavaScript or php.

Is there a way to do that? The strings look like `dfc6d9ff5a1d394e` or 
`2b514f260aad317a`.
The background is that these are unique ids and I want to convert them to unique colours...

Comment: What color is `dfc6d9ff5a1d394e` supposed to turn into?

Comment: Any random color. I did not try anything cause I don't know what to to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these IDs are reasonably random, ie: part of a hash or UUID try:

```
$str = 'dfc6d9ff5a1d394e';
$hexcolor = '#' . substr($str, 0, 6);
//output: #dfc6d9
```

or if they are somewhat more uniform and you'd like something a bit more 'random' without actually being random:

```
$str = 'dfc6d9ff5a1d394e';
$hexcolor = '#' . substr(md5($str), 0, 6);
//output: #8daadd
```

or if you want to get *fancier* [here's a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488174/generate-high-contrast-random-color-using-php/14489553#14489553) with more in-depth code.

Comment: Seems legit... Dump that I did not think about simple trim...